# Program cannot find image directory when run from IDE, but CAN when run from folder?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, directory, textures, codeblocks

When I build, it succeeds with no errors. However, when I run from the IDE, I get an error (my image fails to load because it cannot find the directory).

However, if I go into the folder and run the program(.exe) it finds the image directory perfectly.

```
mTextures.Load(Textures::Background, "../GFX/Background.png");
```

^the line of code giving the directory.

I assume this is a problem with a setting I didn't enter correctly in my compiler?

I am using Code::Blocks on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your debugger's current directory (i.e. the current directory used when you execute the application from within codeblock) is probably incorrect. Check your project settings, and fix the current directory to your target directory (the one which contains the executable itself).

Specific instructions are [here](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=14301.0).

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question and giving me the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using a *relative* path in your file name:

```
"../GFX/Background.png"
```

the `..` is saying "go up one directory form the current directory".  If you want to be able to run your program anywhere, use an *absolute* path, something like:

```
"/home/me/GFX/Background.png"
```

Comment: I tried this, but had the same issue even after placing the GFX folder into the folder with the .exe that the ide builds.

Answer (score 0):

Add the full path where the image exist with double slash.

```
mTextures.Load(Textures::Background, "C:\\Program Files\\..\\..\\GFX\\Background.png");
```

Comment: Im sure this works, but there is a reason I want to use relative paths.