# Codeblocks on Mac not opening .txt input file

Tags: c++, input, codeblocks

I am still new the code blocks and C++ world so bear with me. I am trying to pull from a .txt file. I have checked the name of my .txt file and it is exactly the same as in my code and it is in the same location as my .cpp file. Part of the assignment was to create an “if statement” that displays  "Input file failed to open." if there is an issue with opening the input file. Well that part works. Even though the .txt file is in the right location with the correct name Code Blocks won't pull any information from it. I tested on Windows and my code works perfectly, the issue seems to be a setting on my Mac. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ifstream fin;
fin.open("inFile.txt");

if ( !fin )
    {
        cout << endl << endl
             << "***Program Terminated.***" << endl << endl
             << "Input file failed to open." << endl;
        fin.close();
        return 1; }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the path is valid relative to the directory where the actual application is being executed. This will typically _not_ be the same directory of the source file itself, but rather a build directory of some sort

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program cannot find image directory when run from IDE, but CAN when run from folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937305/program-cannot-find-image-directory-when-run-from-ide-but-can-when-run-from-fol)

Comment: @mnunberg how would I go about finding where it is executing from

Comment: @NO_NAME I did not create this program as a project, I created it as a file.

Comment: @JamieV Try `std::system("pwd")`. This should show current directory.

Comment: @NO_NAME I am literally at a loss for how to insert that into my program...I have only started programming 3 weeks ago. Sorry!

Comment: @JamieV [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) Just paste `system("pwd");` at begining of main function. And don't forget to `#include <cstdlib>`.